# Hola, necesito ayuda con este error: Notice: Undefined index: id

Tags: php, html

actualmente tengo un error que no entiendo como solucionar porque segun yo todo esta correcto pero necesito ayuda ya que llevo 2 días en este problema.

ARCHIVO: topics.php

```
<?php
include("../../app/database/db.php");

$table = 'categorias';

$id = '';
$name = '';
$description = '';

$categorias = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-topic'])) {
    unset($_POST['add-topic']);
    $topic_id = create($table, $_POST);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Categoria creada correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $categoria = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
    $id = $categoria['id'];
    $name = $categoria['name'];
    $description = $categoria['description'];
}

?>
```

ARCHIVO: edit.php

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="text-input">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" class="text-input" <?php echo $description; ?> id="description"></textarea>
      
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <button type="submit" name="update-topic" class="btn" >Update Topic</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

ERROR: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\topics.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\topics.php on line 25

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\topics.php on line 26

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\topics.php on line 27

Comment: Estas mezclando `GET` y `POST`

Comment: `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: Gracias!, no me había dado cuenta de eso.